# Custom route MVC4 with constraints

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-routing

I have an MVC 4 application that i want to create custom route to respective controllers.
The goal is simply to not show the action name in the url, rather only show controller name and parameters.

```
routes.MapRoute(
               "Account", // Route name
               "Account/{param}", // URL with parameters
               new { controller = "Account", action = "Account", param = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
               new { controller = @"^(Account)$" } //Parameter constraints

               );
 routes.MapRoute(
               "Login", // Route name
               "Login/{returnurl}", // URL with parameters
               new { controller = "Login", action = "Login", returnurl = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
               new { controller = @"^(Login)$" }  //Parameter constraints
               );

routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

At the moment i'm using this route above which work fine until i call another action that is not specified in the default parameter/url of each root.

E.g the route to Login/Login or Login/Login?somevalue works as expected to simply not show the action in the url Logn or Login/somevalue. But as soon another action in the same controller is requested the route resolves to Login/Login/Logout for instance. Why is this occurring when i have set the route to match all requests to Login controller?
All actions in the controller have the returnurl parameter

An explanation or clarification on this matter would be greatly appreciated if some could take time and view my routes.

Any help or thoughts would be nice.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please explain this statement 'At the moment i'm using this route above which work fine until i call another action that is not specified in the default parameter/url of each root.'

Comment: which named route works and what exact uri fails?

Comment: @Dave E.g the route to Login/Login or Login/Login?somevalue works as expected to simply not show the action in the url Logn or Login/somevalue. But as soon another action in the same controller is requested the route resolves to Login/Login/Logout for instance. Why is this occurring when i have set the route to match all requests to Login controller?

Comment: are you always taking a variable called returnurl?

Comment: @Dave all actions in the controller have the returnurl parameter